# ПРи клике на кнопку сплывало 4-5 кнопок

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap4

При нажатии на кнопку всплывало 4-5 кнопок, к примеру есть кнопка контакт.
Нажимаю и всплывает кнопки. VK,FC,TW. 
Облазил инет, а там в овнове по клику добавление дивов.

Comment: Это же сколько времени нужно, что бы облазить инет! Делайте как с добавлением дивов, только с кнопками.

Comment: тупнул,надо отдых

Comment: Порадовали вы меня! _От улыбки хмурый день светлей, От улыбки в небе радуга проснётся..._